# Finding <script> element by src, change type and add element?

Tags: jquery

Below is the script element in my code. I want to find it, add an attribute and change the `type` to `"text/plain"`. Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/d402d0261.js" async></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes possible in jquery

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this, but it seems a little redundant as JS runs too late in the page lifecycle for the attribute changes to have any meaningful effect. I'd suggest you change the source instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('script[type="text/javascript"]').attr("type", "text/plain")
```

Select the script tags with attribute `type="text/javascript"` and set it value to `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use select and searching using jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scripts=$("script");
    var searchsrc="https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/d402d0261.js";
    $.each(scripts,function(i,o){
      
      if(o.src==searchsrc){
        o.type="text/plain";
        console.log(o.src);
        console.log(o.type);
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/d402d0261.js" async></script>
```